# Checking if one of 4 variables starts with string &red in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I'm trying to check if one of 4 variables starts with the string "&red" and I'm struggling to get the match to work. At the moment I've got this,

```
if [[ $filemsgCICS = "&red"* || $filemsgCICSU1 = "&red"* || $snufmsgCICS = "&red"* || $snufmsgCICSU1 = "&red"* ]];then
```

but that doesn't work. I can't seem to find a solution that will work. I've tried '&red'* and I've tried \&red* but none of them work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's still not working but adding some more echoes in has highlighted that the variables are not being set correctly. They are set in the following way, `code` snufmsg$word1="&red System $word1 has SNUF terminal $word9 in an disabled state"

Comment: I think it might be that I am using a variable in a variable name as above. Version is ksh 93 (box is Centos 5.6)

Comment: You may want to delete your question since the problem is elsewhere and the code in your question works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax ${variable:offset:length} to get portions of your variables like this:

```
if [[ ${filemsgCICS:0:4} = "&red" || ${filemsgCICSU1:0:4} = "&red" || \
  ${snufmsgCICS:0:4} = "&red" || ${snufmsgCICSU1:0:4} = "&red" ]]; then
```

**Edit:** My comment about * not matching with [[ ]] was wrong. Your method should have worked too if the variables contain the text as expected. So this is just an alternative way.

Comment: Are you sure? `[[…]]` does the matching for me: http://pastebin.com/GMfcj5nw

Comment: This is not correct. http://sprunge.us/fNJX

Comment: It looks like it's not this that's the problem, it's my variable creation. It's not finding the &red because it's not there. See my other question about variables.

Comment: This answer is working beautifully now I've got the variables created correctly. Thanks. I would vote it up if I could.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `awk` and a `for` loop:

```
matched=0
for var in "$filemsgCICS" "$filemsgCICSU1" "$snufmsgCICS" "$snufmsgCICSU1";do
   if [ ! -z "$(printf "%s\n" "$var" | awk '/^\&red/')" ]; then
       matched=1
       break
   fi
done
if [ "$matched" -eq 1 ]; then
   # do stuff...
fi
```

This achieves logical OR semantics by breaking out of the loop at the first variable that matches. You can still achieve this using `awk` only and something like

```
if    [ ! -z "$(printf "%s\n" "$filemsgCICS" | awk ...)" ]\
   || [ ! -z "$(printf "%s\n" "$filemsgCICSU1" ...
```

but using the loop makes it more readable and easier to maintain in my opinion.